# problem when using responsive file, code in responsive file has been add in index.html but can not active?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am newbie with HTML CSS and trying to write a very simple program with HTML CSS with responsive file and here is my problem.

I wrote an index.html file and in this file, I added two classes like this

```
<div class="row contact-content">
                <div class="col col-half contact-info s-col-full">
                    <p><i class="ti-location-pin"></i>Chicago, US</p>
                    <p><i class="ti-mobile"></i>Phone: +00 151515</p>
                    <p><i class="ti-email"></i>Email: mail@mail.com</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-half contact-form s-col-full">
                    <form action="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-half">
                                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Name" required id="" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-half">
                                <input type="email" name="" placeholder="Email" required id="" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mt-8">
                            <div class="col col-full">
                                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Message" required id="" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input class="btn pull-right mt-16" type="submit" value="Send">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As you can see in my code, in the class, I want the class Chicago, US v.v will take up 100% the screen, and the row Name Email v.v will take up 100% the screen too because I add the code

```
.s-col-full {
    width: 100%;
}
```

to the responsive.

But, it does not happen.

Here is what I got in the screen, as you can see, the Chicago US is lying next to Name, Email, Message.[image: my problem]

But, as design, it must lie up the Name, Email, Message (because s-col-full is width: 100% in responsive)

Here is my code, sorry because I can not upload to bitbucket.

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/kfuqch81jqkwk/bai_90

Could you please give me some advice for this problem ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: We can’t download the code files to solve your problem. Pls put your code in stackoverflow snippets or else use code pen or something like that

Comment: are you facing an issue with the CONTACT section or any other section???

Comment: @ArchitGargi : thank you for your comment, I have 2 file styles.css and responsive.css, and in code pen I do not know how to upload 2 file css, could you please tell me how to upload 2 file css to codepen ?

Comment: @Aman : my issue only happen with the CONTACT, another section work very ok, I wrote the code 

.s-col-full {
    width: 100%;
} to use for many case and it work very well, only this case it does not work

Comment: yes, but in your index file you haven't added `` s-col-full`` class in contact section please cross-check your code in index.html

Comment: @nguyencuc2386 U dont have to upload... U need to copy it

Answer (score 1):

**Just code CSS like this:**

```
.contact-content .contact-info,
.contact-content .contact-form {
    width: 100%;
}
```